# mysql -u root -p -> command not found

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create a database, so I started doing it by a video tutorial. When I created a file `.bash_profile` I opened it in the editor and added a command

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

After that I wanted to connect to the mysql server by command `mysql -u root -p`, but it didn't work and showed command not found.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed any MySql server?? And MySql client to connect to it??

Comment: Have you installed the command? How do you know the full path? You appear to be using Linux. Most (if not all) Linux distributions have builtin package managers and host mysql client programs in their repositories. Check the documentation for your exact distro.

Comment: Did you start a new terminal after that? Or ran `source .bash_profile` to apply the changes in your current terminal?

Comment: You should add the directory to the path variable where your mysql client executable is installed. Pls check your installation directory.